# Counter using KeyPress events

Tags: vb.net, counter, keypress, visual-studio-2015

First time posting here, although I'm a frequent visitor when I'm looking for answers. I am new to VB and programming.
My problem is this. I had this figured out in VBA, but I want to convert my "program" to a standalone executable with VB (using Visual Studio 2015)
I want to keep track of certain keypresses done on a textbox, and so far I figured out something that works, but it seems messy.
Can anyone think of a better way of doing

```
    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        Select Case UCase(e.KeyChar) 'For capturing keypresses and adding them
            Case "W" : Label3.Text = Val(Label3.Text) + 1
            Case "R" : Label4.Text = Val(Label4.Text) + 1
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        TextBox1.Text = "" 'Clears the text box after each keypress
    End Sub

    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim WcountA As Integer
        Dim RcountA As Integer
        Dim WcountB As Integer
        Dim RcountB As Integer
        Dim Wavg As Single
        Dim Ravg As Single
        Select Case Button1.Text
            Case "Finish A" 'Finishes first count and stores results in labels
                WcountA = Convert.ToInt32(Label3.Text)
                RcountA = Convert.ToInt32(Label4.Text)
                Button1.Text = "Finish B"
                Label5.Text = WcountA
                Label7.Text = RcountA
                TextBox1.Focus()
                Label3.Text = ""
                Label4.Text = ""
            Case "Finish B" 'Finishes second count and stores in labels
                WcountB = Convert.ToInt32(Label3.Text)
                RcountB = Convert.ToInt32(Label4.Text)
                With Button1
                    .Text = "Finished"
                    .Enabled = False
                End With
                Label6.Text = WcountB
                Label8.Text = RcountB
                Label3.Text = ""
                Label4.Text = ""
                WcountA = Label5.Text
                RcountA = Label7.Text
                WcountB = Label6.Text
                RcountB = Label8.Text
                Wavg = (WcountA + WcountB) / 2
                Ravg = (RcountA + RcountB) / 2

                MsgBox("W average = " & Wavg & vbNewLine & "R average = " & Ravg)
        End Select

    End Sub
End Class
```

On the form I have the textbox that logs the keypress event, labels that increase by 1 with each specific keypess ("W" and "R"), a button that changes its function with each click(finish first count, finish second count) and some labels I had to use to store the first and second count for the final calculation.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of al, you need to take out the counters of the key pres handler like so;

Because they are gone every time the Button1_Click sub ends.

```
 Public Class Form1

    Dim WcountA As Integer
    Dim RcountA As Integer
    Dim WcountB As Integer
    Dim RcountB As Integer
    Dim Wavg As Single
    Dim Ravg As Single

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Select Case UCase(e.KeyChar) 'For capturing keypresses and adding them
        Case "W" : Label3.Text = Val(Label3.Text) + 1
        Case "R" : Label4.Text = Val(Label4.Text) + 1
    End Select
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    TextBox1.Text = "" 'Clears the text box after each keypress
End Sub

Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Select Case Button1.Text
        Case "Finish A" 'Finishes first count and stores results in labels
            WcountA = Convert.ToInt32(Label3.Text)
            RcountA = Convert.ToInt32(Label4.Text)
            Button1.Text = "Finish B"
            Label5.Text = WcountA
            Label7.Text = RcountA
            TextBox1.Focus()
            Label3.Text = ""
            Label4.Text = ""
        Case "Finish B" 'Finishes second count and stores in labels
            WcountB = Convert.ToInt32(Label3.Text)
            RcountB = Convert.ToInt32(Label4.Text)
            With Button1
                .Text = "Finished"
                .Enabled = False
            End With
            Label6.Text = WcountB
            Label8.Text = RcountB
            Label3.Text = ""
            Label4.Text = ""
            WcountA = Label5.Text
            RcountA = Label7.Text
            WcountB = Label6.Text
            RcountB = Label8.Text
            Wavg = (WcountA + WcountB) / 2
            Ravg = (RcountA + RcountB) / 2

            MsgBox("W average = " & Wavg & vbNewLine & "R average = " & Ravg)
    End Select

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: That makes so much sense, now I feel kind of like an idiot! Thanks, I'll try that and re-evaluate my code!

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing, works better and looks cleaner. Thanks Lectere for pointing me to the right path!

```
    Public Class Form1
    Dim WcountA As Integer
    Dim RcountA As Integer
    Dim WcountB As Integer
    Dim RcountB As Integer
    Dim Wavg As Single
    Dim Ravg As Single
    Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        Select Case UCase(e.KeyChar) 'For capturing keypresses and adding them
            Case "W" : lblWcount.Text = Val(lblWcount.Text) + 1
            Case "R" : lblRcount.Text = Val(lblRcount.Text) + 1
            Case Convert.ToChar(13) : Button1_Click(sender, e)
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        TextBox1.Text = "" 'Clears the text box after each keypress
    End Sub

    Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Select Case Button1.Text
            Case "Finish A" 'Finishes first count and stores results in variables
                If lblWcount.Text = vbNullString Then 'checks for empty values and treats them as 0
                    WcountA = 0
                Else
                    WcountA = lblWcount.Text
                End If
                If lblRcount.Text = vbNullString Then 'checks for empty values and treats them as 0
                    RcountA = 0
                Else
                    RcountA = lblRcount.Text
                End If
                Button1.Text = "Finish B"
                lbl_1.Text = WcountA
                lbl_2.Text = RcountA
                TextBox1.Focus()
                lblWcount.Text = vbNullString
                lblRcount.Text = vbNullString
                lblcount.Text = "Count B"
            Case "Finish B" 'Finishes second count and stores results in variables
                lblcount.Text = vbNullString
                If lblWcount.Text = vbNullString Then
                    WcountB = 0
                Else
                    WcountB = lblWcount.Text
                End If
                If lblRcount.Text = vbNullString Then
                    RcountB = 0
                Else
                    RcountB = lblRcount.Text
                End If
                With Button1
                    .Text = "Reset"
                End With
                lbl_3.Text = WcountB
                lbl_4.Text = RcountB
                lblWcount.Text = vbNullString
                lblRcount.Text = vbNullString
                Wavg = (WcountA + WcountB) / 2
                Ravg = (RcountA + RcountB) / 2
                MsgBox("W average = " & Wavg & vbNewLine & "R average = " & Ravg)
                Button1.Focus()
            Case "Reset" 'Resets values
                Dim i As Integer
                For i = 1 To 4 'clears labels that start with lbl_ (1 through 4)
                    Dim myLabel As Label = CType(Controls("lbl_" & i), Label)
                    myLabel.Text = vbNullString
                Next
                Initial() ' calls initial form state
        End Select
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Initial() 'calls initial form state at load up
    End Sub
    Private Sub Initial() 'initial state sub
        lblcount.Text = "Count A"
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Button1.Text = "Finish A"

    End Sub
End Class
```

I managed to use loops for clearing labels, and also made pressing Enter during the KeyPress event be treated as a button click.
Loving this feeling of accomplishment when I finally figure something out on something new to me! Love pages like this one where one can learn so much!